# Find a bijection between two sets of points that minimizes the sum of pairwise distances.

Tags: optimization, permutations, discrete-optimization

We are given two sets of points $\{a_1, \ldots a_n\}$ and $\{b_1, \ldots, b_n\}$ in Euclidean space ( say $2$ dimensional). We are looking for a bijection $a_i \mapsto b_{\sigma(i)}$ so that the sum of distances 
$$\sum_{i} |a_i - b_{\sigma(i)}|$$ is minimal. Is there an efficient algorithm  to find such a bijection ( for large $n$)?

---

If the points are on the line the bijection is the one preserving the order, so that is not hard.

Here is an approach that does not give a solution in general: Find the pair $(a_i, b_j)$ with the smallest distance, and pair these points. Continue with the rest of the points in the same way.

Comment: How did you conclude that that last approach is not a solution?

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Oh, we know the solution in $1$ dimension that the pairing has to preserve the order... so it's easy to get a counterexample

Comment: http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~kvaradar/paps/main-focs.pdf

Comment: The Hungarian Algorithm will do the trick, at a cost polynomial in $n$.

Comment: @evil999man: Oh, I see, thanks! However, I think the problem there is just a bit different. But yeah, there should be some pointers there.

Comment: @kimchi lover: Thanks, that does it!

Comment: Oh, the graph here is bipartite. This survey talks about it: https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall08/cps234/projects/sayan_proj.pdf

Comment: @evil999man: Thanks, that's  just great!

Comment: @orangeskid this may seem like a dumb question, but I can't seem to find a rigorous proof for the fact that sorting solves the 1-dimensional problem (all points on a line). Do you happen to know one ?

Comment: @Ewaren: can you see the argument in the case $n=2$? (two sets of two points each). Check that the optimal pairing is smaller to smaller, larger to larger. Now, for general $n$, if some $a_i < a_j$ paired to $b_{\phi(i)} > b_{\phi(j)}$ then we can decrease the sum of distances if we pair $a_i$ to $b_{\phi(j)}$ and $a_j$ to $b_{\phi(i)}$. So, for an optimal pairing, the $a_i$ and the $b_{\phi(i)}$'s have to be in the same order.

Comment: @orangeskid thank you very much ! Definitely not as trivial as I initially thought 

Comment: @Ewaren: for an optimal pairing, the segments $a_i b_{\phi(i)}$ and $a_j b_{\phi(j)}$ should not intersect (except at the ends perhaps). That implies pairing in increasing order.  The proof is rather like this: if not in order, then can still decrease, so not optimal.  And there is an optimal one... Glad it helps.

Comment: @Ewaren: my previous comment is not entirely correct: the pairing in increasing order is optimal, but even for $n=2$, it may not be the only one . But definitely, by reducing the number of inversions, the sum is not increased.  The observation about intersecting segments is not always correct.  Thank you.