# Efficient algorithm to find the permutation that reduces distance between two lists

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, algorithms, discrete-optimization, permutation-matrices

Two lists $A$ and $B$ contain equal number of elements. List $A$ is in ascending order. List $B$ is randomly ordered.

$$
A = \{a_1, ..., a_N\}, a_i \leq a_{i+1}
$$
$$
B = \{b_1, ..., b_N\}
$$

What is an efficient algorithm to find the permutation of $B$ for which $|B-A|_1$ or $|B-A|_2$ is minimum?

If the solution to the above problem is simply the ascending order of $B$, then it is trivial to use any sorting algorithm to find the solution. But I am stuck at establishing whether it is true for lists of any arbitrary length.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Longer than a comment. In this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2406917/find-a-bijection-between-two-sets-of-points-that-minimizes-the-sum-of-pairwise-d)  it was about the $l^1$ distance.
The [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm#Matrix_formulation) was suggested. I was thinking that naively one could try to minimize
$$\sum c_{ij} a_{ij}$$
where $c_{ij}$ positive are the given costs and $(a_{ij})$ vary over the doubly-stochastic matrices. Then we could do linear programming and get a solution at an extreme point of the polytope of doubly stochastic matrices, which will be a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix#Birkhoff%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem). But it seems the H alg beats this naive approach.

$\bf{Added:}$ As Rob Pratt indicated, for $l^2$ the best matching is order preserving. Same for $l^1$, I sketched a proof in the comments to my posting. Interesting for other $l^q$ norms.